# getting data in child directive from parent directive in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a parent directive in which its controller makes a call through a service to get some data.

```
sharedService.getData(options).then(function(data){
    $scope.data = data;
});
```

Now i need this data in my child controller.

What i have already tried are the ff:
1) Through $timeout i get the data after sometime but it doesn't seem a good solution impacting performance

2) watchCollection() - i watched if newValue !== oldValue
problem being the data is huge so it takes a toll of performance

Now the issue i'm getting is the child directive gets executed after parent BUT before the data comes back from the service and i'm not able to get that data in my child directive via $scope.data.

Is there any solution to get data from parent directive to child directive when i have to wait for data to come in parent?

Answer (score 1):

You can include your parent directive controller in your child directive by using [require](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('dirParent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {

          }],

  };
})
.directive('dirChild', function() {
  return {
    require: '^dirParent', // include directive controller
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {

    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, paretCtrl) {
      var data = paretCtrl.getMyData();
    }
  };

})
```

Comment: the code in link function would get executed before i would even get data. it's someService.getData(options).then(function(data){}). I need data so that i can use it to render some stuff

Comment: share object reference between your service and controller then it will update every time the object change so, define a sharedService.data (where data is an object) asign it to your controller ($scope.data = sheredService.data) and then pass the reference to your child dir, in link function, var data = paretCtrl.data (do not share primitive just objects);

Comment: i'm sharing a scope object right now $scope.data = data;
but this doesn't show the updated value of $scope.data because of .then()
i don't get the updated value.my child directive executes before i even get data. Can't use $timeout as i mentioned above.

Comment: no, $scope.data = data; is executed after data is found, move your code that define data in your service, and, assign  sheredService.data to scope.data it will be {} in the start, after promise is resolved, it will update, as well as scope.data

Answer (score 0):

It's always a best to use service for communication and and business logic. Here is an example. Please check. This might solve your problem.

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('messageService', function() {
    return {
      message: null
    }
  })
  .directive('parentDir', function() {
    return {
      scope: {}, //isolate
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="PDirInput"/><button ng-click="send()">Send</button>',
      controller: function($scope, messageService) {
        $scope.send = function() {
          messageService.message = $scope.PDirInput;
        }
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('childDir', function() {
    return {
      scope: {}, //isolate
      template: '<code>{{CDirInput.message}}</code>',
      controller: function($scope, messageService) {
        $scope.CDirInput = messageService;
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.31" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <HR/>Parent Directive
  <parent-dir></parent-dir>
  <br/>
  <HR/>Child Directive
  <child-dir></child-dir>
  <HR/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first of all the structure you have provided shows sibling directives, not parent child directives.
second, i'm already using a service in my parent directive to get some data which i want in my child directive. there is a .then() there due to which the child link function executes before i get my data.